# How do I read a settings value from the web.config file in an ASP.NET application?

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, .net-4.0, web-config

I'm trying to use the following command:

```
Dim xmlFilePath As String = _
    System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("XmlFilePath")
```

to retrieve the following setting:

```
<applicationSettings>
    <MySolution.WebProject.My.MySettings>
        <setting name="XmlFilePath" serializeAs="String">
            <value>C:\ASP.NET\Folder\MessageLog</value>
        </setting>
    </MySolution.WebProject.My.MySettings>
</applicationSettings>
```

However, `xmlFilePath` shows up as `Nothing` after that line of code is run.

What's the correct code to get a setting out of the web.config file in an ASP.NET application?

*NOTE: Although you can add keys individually to the `<appsettings>` tag, I'm trying to figure out how to use it with the "Settings" tab in the project's properties.*

Comment: i think you can not add this tag MySolution.WebProject.My.MySettings directly inside appsetting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look in

```
My.MySettings.Default.XmlFilePath
```

Comment: What's with the downvote? Replace `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("XmlFilePath")`with this and you can access your setting.

Comment: I don't understand why you received the downvote either. I think that may be the answer I'm looking for.  I'll it when I get into work today. Thanks!

Comment: This ended up being exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Typically i see see this as being done different way.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="XmlFilePath" value="C:\yourpath here" />
</appSettings>
```

Then you would use the method you describe, as that is the way that the "ConfigurationManager" works.

Comment: Hmm...maybe I did it wrong.  I added the setting via the "Settings" tab in the project's properties window and it generated the deeply nested settings.